# Slim PHP Not returning the correct Status Code

Tags: php, slim

I'm creating my first api, and I chose to use Slim PHP, so far, I think it's a great lightweight framework to do the basics of what I need. The only issue I've really had was my route responses not returning the correct status codes. I want to return 200 on a successful login, and a 403 on a failed login with incorrect credentials. All I get back is a 200 no matter what it returns. The logic is working, because I can see the correct JSON being returned, just the status code doesn't get changed.

Index.php

```
 <?php
    use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
    use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

    require  'vendor/autoload.php';

    $app = new \Slim\App;

    $app->options('/{routes:.+}', function ($request, $response, $args) {
        return $response;
    });

    $app->add(function ($req, $res, $next) {
        $response = $next($req, $res);
        return $response
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://mysite')
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,    Content-Type, Accept, Origin, Authorization')
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    });

    require_once 'api/login.php';

    $app->run();
```

Login.php

```
$app->post('/api/login', function ($request, $response){
    require_once 'db.php';

    $q = "SELECT * FROM blog_admin WHERE username = ? AND password = ?";

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($q);
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $user, $pass);

    $user = $request->getParsedBody()['username'];
    $pass = md5($request->getParsedBody()['password']);

    if($stmt->execute()){
        $stmt->store_result();

        if($stmt->num_rows > 0){
            $token = md5(uniqid($user, true));
            date_default_timezone_set("America/Toronto");
            $logged_in = date('Y/m/d');
            $data = array(
                "flash" => 'success',
                "message" => '<strong>SUCCESS:</strong> You have entered the correct login information! Please wait while you are redirected...',
                '_token' => $token,
                'logged_in' => $logged_in
            );

            $q = "UPDATE blog_admin SET _token=?, last_logged_in=?";
            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($q);
            $stmt->bind_param('ss', $token, $logged_in);

            if($stmt->execute()){
                $response->withJson($data, 200);
            }else{
                $data = array(
                    "flash" => 'danger',
                    "message" => '<strong>ERROR:</strong> Could not login! Please try again later!'
                );
                $response->withJson($data, 403);
            }
        }else{
            $data = array(
                "flash" => 'danger',
                "message" => '<strong>ERROR:</strong> The Username/Password you have entered is incorrect. Please try again.'
            );
            $response->withJson($data, 403);
        }
    }else{
        $data = array(
            "flash" => 'danger',
            "message" => '<strong>ERROR:</strong> Could Not Run the SQL'
        );

        $response->withJson($data, 500);
    }

    return $response;
});
```

I'm not sure what the issue might be, so any ideas will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PSR-7 Response which slim3 uses is a [immutable value object](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/concepts/value-objects.html), so it cannot be changed.

F.ex.

```
$response->withJson($data, 200);
```

Will not change `$response` it returns the changed Response so you either have to return this

```
return $response->withJson($data, 200);
```

or you need to reassign the variable with the new value, and then return it at the end of the route function.

```
$response = $response->withJson($data, 200);
// other code
return $response;
```